convert sandbox img url to UIImage
I saved the image URL in userdefault, and then I read it, but I can't view it inside UIImageView
print("UserDefaults url: \(String(describing: defaults.url(forKey: "urlPhoto")))")

file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/HI5648UUU-B7777-9999-4444-KUG6546848/Documents/landscape.png

@IBOutlet weak var photoUser: UIImageView!

photoUser.image = (defaults.data(forKey: "urlPhoto") ?? UIImage(named: "photoPlaceholder")) as? Data

if userdefault is empty then load photoPlaceholder

Does it even compile? You saved a path, no? So you need to call UIImageinit(contentsOfFile:) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624112-init

if let path = defaults.url(forKey: "urlPhoto") { photoUser.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path) } else { photoUser.image = UIImage(named: "photoPlaceholder") } ?

Thanks Larme, that's how it works.

You shouldn't do that, because the path of the URL HI5648UUU-B7777-9999-4444-KUG6546848 always changes after each launch.
The better approach is to cache the suffix and the file extension only, which in this case is landscape.png, to .documentDirectory. And then load it with:
let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
let urlPhoto = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "urlPhoto")
if let urlPhoto, let fullPath = documentDirectory?.appendingPathComponent(urlPhoto) {
    return UIImage(contentsOfFile: fullPath.path)
} else {
    return UIImage(named: "photoPlaceholder")
}


Nowadays URL.documentsDirectory returns the non-optional URL of the documents directory in the application container.
